# R: Legend position is c(1,0.5), but it is still inside my chart. How can I move it outside without it beeing cut off

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, pie-chart, legend-properties

I am plotting and saving a pie Chart and want the legend to be closer to the chart than with no position specification.

When using
This puts the legend inside my pie and when moving the legend even furher to the right eg 1.5 the text gets cut off in the jpg file.

```
slices <- c(1,33,39)
label <- c('obligatory school','Highschool','College or University')


plot_df <- data.frame(
  group = label,
  value = slices
)

bar<- ggplot(plot_df, aes(x="", y=value , fill=group))+  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")

pie <- bar + coord_polar("y", start=0) +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  legend.text=element_text(size=15), legend.position=c(1,0.5))  #

print(pie)
ggsave('test.jpg',width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 150, units = "in")
```

Why is the plot behaving that way and how can I get my legend just outside of my Chart without it beeing cut of?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The edited code should work now.